# Philips 170S does not display fine gray tones but other colors fine

Tags: display, colors, display-settings, calibration

I have a problem with my secondary monitor: I calibrated it with Windows Color Calibration, and I have the problem that it displays grey tones (like the grey background of the Stack Exchange code block) as white. All colors other than that seem normal.

Do I need to set any more preferences that may resolve this issue?

- External monitor: PHILIPS 170S (1280 x 1024)
- Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M
- Connection: Graphics card HDMI out, [HDMI to VGA converter](http://www.amazon.de/dp/B00GJP2PZS), to Monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely that model of computer monitor.

PCMag noted this in their review of the monitor.

> [Philips 170S Review & Rating | PCMag.com](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,1644186,00.asp)
>
> Cons: Limited viewing angle. **Weak on light-gray performance.** Tilt-only base.
>
> ...
>
> Light-gray performance was weak, even after we adjusted the contrast
>   settings.